# MariaDb 10.4 not starting in a freebsd jail after update

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

ran a pkg update and mariadb seems to be broken.
Cant find out what the reason might be after 2h our googling and digging.
Help to figure out would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
The hostname.err shows no additional entries after DB start (the try to start)

FreeBSD nextcloud 12.2-RELEASE-p6 FreeBSD 12.2-RELEASE-p6 df578562304(HEAD) TRUENAS  amd64

mariadb104-client-10.4.19      Multithreaded SQL database (client)
mariadb104-server-10.4.19      Multithreaded SQL database (server)

```
root@nextcloud:~ # service mysql-server start
Starting mysql.
root@nextcloud:~ # service mysql-server status
mysql is not running.
root@nextcloud:~ #

root@nextcloud:/tmp # cat /etc/rc.conf
cron_flags="$cron_flags -J 15"

# Disable Sendmail by default
sendmail_enable="NO"
sendmail_submit_enable="NO"
sendmail_outbound_enable="NO"
sendmail_msp_queue_enable="NO"

# Run secure syslog
syslogd_flags="-c -ss"

# Enable IPv6
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
apache24_enable="yes"
mysql_enable="yes"
redis_enable="yes"
php_fpm_enable="yes"
```

Server Startup  sh -x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
https://pastebin.com/UdEC8Th6

```
root@nextcloud:~ # cat /usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything, see
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#option-groups
#
[client-server]
port    = 3306
socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock
#socket  = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

[image][image]

[image]

Tried to update again:

```
root@nextcloud:/usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d # mysqlcheck -u root -p --version
mysqlcheck  Ver 2.7.4-MariaDB Distrib 10.4.19-MariaDB, for FreeBSD12.2 (amd64)
root@nextcloud:/usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d # service mysql-server stop
mysql not running? (check /var/db/mysql/nextcloud.pid).
root@nextcloud:/usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d # service mysql-server status
mysql is not running.
root@nextcloud:/usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d # mariadb-upgrade --datadir=/tmp
mariadb-upgrade: the '--datadir' option is always ignored
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
root@nextcloud:/usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d #
```

Comment: always check the error log it tells you what went wrong also clarify what update you run

Comment: yeah but what is the error log in this case?  /var/db/mysql/nextcloud.err prompts no new errors, last entry seems to be from october last year

Comment: myabe it is nit enabled or written in the db https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-log/

Comment: thanks for your help. The file /usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d/server.cnf says log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/mysqld.err - but that file is not existing. Attached screenshots

Comment: ah found something, maybe u can have a view on the last screenshot

Comment: please don't post images

Comment: that looks more like your upograde went wrong or you didn't run the upgrade script, see how to upgrade on the webpage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127150/discussion-between-krautmaster-and-nbk).